# XCode - Dynamically created labels, when i change the text it changes it for the last one only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

So i have a bunch of dynamically loaded labels..

Each of them has the same name because there is no telling how many there will be..

I have another method (not the one that created the labels) changing the text for one of the labels, but when i run it only the last label that was created will change..

I need it to change the one that has a certain tag or something..

Help is much appreciated, this website is yet to let me down.

Comment: Show your code ... how are you changing your label ?

Comment: oh really ....... if you know too much then why are you questioning ?

Comment: Yes, you should put some correlated code.

Comment: I am not sure if you read my response wrong but i am not saying i know too much.. i am saying there is too much code to show.. if you tell me which part then i will gladly show it..

Comment: This is the part that changes the label `self.myLabel.text = myString;`

Comment: " another method (not the one that created the labels) changing the text for one of the labels," post the "another method"

Comment: Agreed unless you show some code we can't help.

Comment: I posted the other method above..

Comment: @user1533419 -Look.. When you creates your your buttons, labels, etc via loop ... they all have same name... so you can not identify them with their tag numbers ... like if(label.tag == 2 ){ label.text = @"hello" } ... in this case if condition will be always true, because some label defiantly has tag number 2.. and then you are trying to change text of label.. it always change the last label value..... you will have to identify label with its View or frame.. as waheeda have told...

Comment: I don't know why people are asking questions on Stack Overflow and are afraid that if they show the code, someone else would see that, figure out what do they do and copy the idea. Such way of thinking will never succeed.

Comment: That wasn't the way i was thinking, i just didn't know which part to show, and there was too much to show it all..

Comment: You could have posted any code connected with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.myLabel  cannot be connected to multiple labels, so it will contain the reference of last created label, you will have to create new label every time, and you can't track them by class properties, you have to access label by their tag.

you can set tag for each label, below is sample code,

```
 for(int i=0; i< numberOfLabels; i++)
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.tag = i; // do not use tag 0 here.. u can use i+1, or i+100.. something like this.
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

to access labels,

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag: labelTag];
```

Comment: Thanks but i have already set the tag upon its creation, i need to know how to change the text of a label with a specific tag.

Answer (score 2):

Okay since you dont have any code to show i guess i have to speculate.

What i understood is that you are creating Dynamic `UILabels` in ur code and you want to access them. Since you have same name for all the `UILabels` you might me loosing the previous `UILabel` when every time you create a new `UILabel`. So in order to keep track of how many `UILabel` you created you must add them in an Array. Declare an `NSMutableArray` in your `viewController.h` file and make sure in the `viewDidLoad` u allocate it like

```
arrForLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Since it is an `NSMutableArray` you can add object to it.

So when u create a `UILabel` make sure you add the same `UILabel` in the **Array** as well
for Instance

```
[arrForLabels addObject:yourLabel];
```

you can try to `NSLog` your **Array** to see its content.

Now all youu got to do is to Create a weak link like that

```
UILabel *tempLabel = [arrForLabels objectAtIndex:1];
```

now `tempLabel` will be the `UILabel` to change **text**

```
tempLabel.text = @"My New Text";
```

It will work fine.
Feel free to ask for any issues in it.