# XCode - Whats the best way to change the identifier of UILabels that are created in a loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am creating labels in a loop.

How can i make it so each label has a different identifier so i can retrieve the text of a specific one at a later time?

Comment: You mention you want to set the label's "name".  What exactly does that mean?

Comment: okay without any offense Why would some one do that....??? the Variable names are handled by the compiler, the user wont be able to see variable name on the simulator.

Comment: I need to do this so each label that my loop creates don't have the same name and i can call a specific one as i need to..

Comment: I have edited the question now, it should be more clear.

Comment: repost of [XCode - Dynamically created labels, when i change the text it changes it for the last one only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578647/xcode-dynamically-created-labels-when-i-change-the-text-it-changes-it-for-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the label to a dictionary, and set the key to your labelName, and the object to your UILabel.

Then, whenever you want to access the variable, you use the objectForKey:myVar method of the NSDictionary

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a static language so you can't. You should create an array or dictionary, depending on your needs, to put your labels in.

And by the way, don't forget asterisk when you are declaring pointers.

Comment: That would set the text in the label to my variable.. i need to set the name of the label to my variable.

Comment: This changes the text displayed on screen. I'm not sure if that's what he pretends, or if he rather wants to assign the variable name based on a given string.

Comment: It can't be done, but there are workarounds to access a variable through a string. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do it by setting the tag of the label

if you do it through a for loop you could do :

```
for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    [aLabel setTag:i];
```