# How to create dynamically Labels in series iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch

that's the question, I wanna draw a dinamic screen in xCode, depending of the amount of labels comming from a webServer, is something like so...

```
for (int i = 0; i< [webserver.arraylabels count]; i++){
   UILabel *label[i];
   label[i] = [functions createLabel:[[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] textLabel]
                                                   locationX:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] locationX]
                                                   locationY:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] locationY]
                                                 heightControl:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] heightControl]
                                                  widthControl:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] widthControl]
                                                adjustmentControl:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

[cell addSubview:label[i]];
}
```

[functions createLabel...] is a function which returns me an UILabel object type...

if I run this I get an error because of the [i] on the label's name, how do I do this??

thanks in advance for your support

Comment: Why do you need it at all? Just use `UILabel *label = [functions createLabel];`...

Comment: because I want to put them on several locations or tablecells, and like a formulary, I'm thinking of  adding textfields as well and set lenghts to them, kind of keyboards, assign events to them, but for doing that I need them to have a different name like textField1, textField2, textField3.... label1, label2, label3

Comment: Ain't need "different names" for that. A raw C array is fine (just declare it outside the loop), an `NSMutableArray` would be even better.

Comment: I think this is what you mean isn't it??? (second answer)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578647/xcode-dynamically-created-labels-when-i-change-the-text-it-changes-it-for-the

and what do you think of the first answer :p

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer thanks to H2CO3

```
NSMutableArray *arregloControles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i< [webserver.arraylabels count]; i++){
   UILabel *control;
   control = [functions createLabel:[[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] textLabel]
                                                   locationX:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] locationX]
                                                   locationY:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] locationY]
                                                 heightControl:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] heightControl]
                                                  widthControl:[webserver.arraylabels objectAtIndex:i] widthControl]
                                                adjustmentControl:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

[cell addSubview:control];

[arregloControles addObject:control];
}
```

and to call it back H2CO3 suggested:

```
UILabel *label = [arregloControles objectAtIndex:0]; //no casting required
```

or

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag: labelTag];
```